# How to click on button in popup dialog that isn't in page source

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to write a script to legitimately mine coins in Agar.io by clicking the "Free Coins" button once every hour. To do this, I'm using Selenium's Firefox webdriver in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://agar.io")
browser.find_element_by_id("freeCoins").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//canvas/button[1]").click()
browser.quit()
```

By viewing the HTML source of the Agar.io webpage, I was able to find the ID of the "Free Coins" button to click on it, but in order to harvest the coins I need to click on the first button in the popup dialog that comes up:
[image: Free Coins popup dialog]

I can't find the source code for the popup dialog, so I don't know how to find the "20 Coins" button to click it using Selenium.

In addition, there is often a popup dialog on the webpage when it first loads advertising some sort of sale on game purchases. It has a close button which I would also need to click using Selenium, but again I can't find the source code for it so I don't know how to.

Is there a way that I can click on these buttons using Selenium without being able to see their IDs or classes in the webpage's source code?

Comment: Wait.. so when you inspect the element of the button it doesn't bring you to the right html segment? Are you right clicking on the Free coins button and using inspect element?

Comment: @chackerian No, it doesn't. It just selects this line `<canvas height="1024" width="880" style="transform: translateZ(0px); width: 0px; height: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"></canvas>`, and highlights a 1024x880 area including the dialog and a lot of padding around it.

Comment: can you please search for "free coins" in the HTML, see what you find?

Comment: @YuZhang I've already done that and the only result that shows up is the button with the ID "freeCoins". The ones in the popup aren't found.

Comment: I see what your talking about. hmm. The class for the div surrounding it is "openfl-content". I googled that and found https://github.com/openfl/openfl. If you read about Openflow maybe you will be closer to finding a solution

Comment: are those elements (you can't click) inside some iframe?